# Tensorflow: Getting LSTM to 100% in converting date time formats

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, autoencoder, transformer-model

I created a bidirectional seq2seq endcoder-decoder network, which aims at formating different datetypes to a german datetime format as: *day_written_out, day.month.year*

So as an example I have the string **12-27-1992** and I expect the model to predict **Sunday, 27.12.1992**.

After training, the model reaches a valid_accuracy of **98%**. Further investigation showed, that the model nearly always predicted the date itself correct, **but** the model is not able to extract the correct **day**. So instead of predicting **Sunday, 27.12.1992** it predicts **Wednesday, 27.12.1992**.
Only 5% of the days are predicted correctly.

I think, that the issues lies in the LSTM I use, even though its bidirectional, but since the day is the first element that is predicted, the model does not have alot of information for predicting the correct day, since at timestep 0 the model hasnt seen any date values yet. Is this correct?

So my question is, why is this model not capable of predicting the correct day? And would a tranformer architecture, which is capable of reading the whole sequence at a time, be able to solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I think, that the issues lies in the LSTM I use, even though its bidirectional, but since the day is the first element that is predicted, the model does not have alot of information for predicting the correct day, since at timestep 0 the model hasnt seen any date values yet.

Try generate 27.12.1992 - Wednesday instead to see if that does anything.

Honestly i don't think any model can predict correctly with that data